# Calling other tools from my tool

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, command-line, terminal

I'm making a tool that finds folders with specific name and I want to compress those folders using the zip command

How can I run the zip command from my tool to compress the folders?

Comment: You can run `usr/bin/zip` via `NSTask`

Comment: @vadian like NSTask(@"usr/bin/zip") and how do I pass the arguments like I do with zip ( zip folder -a -c ) ?

Comment: Please read the answers in the duplicate questions.

Comment: @vadian NSTask doesn't work on ios